# Sharepoint 2010 : Version History Null reference error

Tags: version-history

I am unable to view the version history of any items in a list in SharePoint 2010 farm. It is throwing Null reference error when I try to view the item's version history. It was visible until August. No patching / changes done on the site.

Error message :

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Please let me know if there is a solution to resolve this issue.

Comment: show your code as well

Comment: Is it happening only for 1 list ? or all list/document in sites ? did you try to create new list and enabled version history and make some edits there and check if it is working..!

Comment: it is happening for 1 list. I am able to view the version history for other lists. Also version history is working as expected for the new lists too.